# External CT Related Lists - Examples - CAML - LINQ to SharePoint

Tags: caml-query, list-definition, linq

I'm trying to return related data via External Content Types.  I was wondering which is better to use, CAML queries or LINQ to SharePoint?  I'm fine with writing CAML queries besides the relating part but haven't used LINQ to SharePoint that much.

Are there any good examples that anyone is aware of for returning data via new CAML queries that support relation data along with LINQ to SharePoint examples?  Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Too bad, but external content types and Linq to SharePoint does not work together. It may be possible with some extensive hacking into the code, but the SPMETAL does not OOTB support this.

Comment: Are there any good examples of retrieving related data via External Lists, or External Content Types, or sp lists in general?  Didn't know if there were any sites that anyone recommends since I could spend hours digging through google/bing search returns.  Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend the book Professional Business Connectivity Services by Scot Hillier (http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Business-Connectivity-SharePoint-Programmer/dp/047061790X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1311799190&sr=8-1). Another good start is, of course MSDN. Channel 9 also provides a lot of information on BCS, external lists and external ct. Please not that ECT is not the solution for everything. Writing data back can get complicated. Some MVP's even recommend not to write back relational data